# What's the name of the song at 9:53 of episode 471 in Naruto: Shppuden?

Tags: naruto, music

I can't find the name of the song anywhere, and it's really bugging me. I need it as relaxation music. The song is at 9:53 of [this episode](http://www.crunchyroll.com/naruto-shippuden/episode-471-the-two-of-themalways-716119).

Comment: Have you tried music recognition apps like Shazam? Have you looked at the soundtrack listing?

Answer (score 1):

I think the song you're looking for is this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IkbQ71K3n1M. I'm not sure what song your referring to because there is like 3 songs in this episode.